# CSS - Animation Effect Issue

Tags: html, css, css-animations

The following animation is not working. Not sure what is wrong. Circles need to be bouncing with each circle having a delay giving it a snake effect. If I set the circle to position absolute it works but i dont want them to be absolute because then all the circles stacked behind eachother which will require margin-left to separate each circle from eachother and I dont want that.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
}


body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.circle-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  column-gap: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}


.circle{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bouncingCircles 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

#one{
  background-color: blue;
  animation-delay: -0.25s
}
#two{
  background-color: orange;
  animation-delay: -0.55s
}
#three{
  background-color: purple;
  animation-delay: -0.65s
}
#four{
  background-color: red;
  animation-delay: -0.75s;
}
#five{
  background-color: limegreen;
  animation-delay: -0.80s;
}

@keyframes bouncingCircles{
  0%{
    top:-100px
  }
  100%{
    top:200px
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
    <title>Training</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="circle-container">
      <div class="circle" id="one"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="two"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="three"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="four"></div>
      <div class="circle" id="five"></div>
    </div>

    <!--<input id="uploadImage" type="file" multiple class="sd">-->
    <!--<canvas id="scene"></canvas>-->
    <script type="module" src="training.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for absolute positioning. Just set them to relative:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  list-style: none;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  column-gap: 40px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: bouncingCircles 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  position: relative;
}

#one {
  background-color: blue;
  animation-delay: -0.25s
}

#two {
  background-color: orange;
  animation-delay: -0.55s
}

#three {
  background-color: purple;
  animation-delay: -0.65s
}

#four {
  background-color: red;
  animation-delay: -0.75s;
}

#five {
  background-color: limegreen;
  animation-delay: -0.80s;
}

@keyframes bouncingCircles {
  0% {
    top: -100px
  }
  100% {
    top: 200px
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unicons.iconscout.com/release/v4.0.0/css/line.css">
<div class="circle-container">
  <div class="circle" id="one"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="two"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="three"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="four"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="five"></div>
</div>
```